# Provide separation between fixed & collapsing tool bar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following XML material design profile built inside a menu fragment.

The problem is that the coordinator layout and the menu tool bar are in the same position which hides the top and bottom of collapsing tool bar. I used the collapsing tool bar from already existing project of mine, but when I tried to implement in in my menu fragment I hit this problem.

How do I set a margin between the menu toolbar and the collapsing tool bar?

Here's what my previous project looked like, for reference.

[image]

Here is the new after I added the collapsing tool bar inside menu fragment:

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout


    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:src="@drawable/pic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

     </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/bg_main"
                android:text="scroll down to save"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/account" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/pfname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="First Name"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/account" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/plname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Last Name"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/phone" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/pphonenb"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Phone"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/email" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/pemail"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Email"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <com.rey.material.widget.Button
                    android:id="@+id/btsave"
                    style="@style/DarkRaiseColorButtonRippleStyle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:background="@color/bg_main"
                    app:rd_backgroundColor="@color/bg_main"
                    app:rd_enable="true"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    style="@style/fab"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white_24dp"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Reworded for clarity, broke thoughts into separate sentences, applied proper capitalization, clarified title.